# mysql Pdo won't sort by name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having trouble with sorting the rows of a database which I connected via a pdo object.
It just won't sort.
I want to sort by the productnames(varchar).
hopefully someone can help me

here's the code:

```
[...]

$db = new PDO($serverPDO, $user, $pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

[...]

if ($_SESSION['sorted'] == 1) {
    $ordered = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `produkte` ORDER BY 'produkte.preis'");
while ($order = $ordered->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;padding:20px'>".$order['produkte.name']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;padding:20px'>".$order['produkte.beschreibung']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;padding:20px'>".$order['produkte.preis']." Euro</td>";
}           
} else {
    [...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'produkte.preis'

in single quotes will be interpreted as a string value, probably the equivalent of `order by 1`  resulting in no meaningful ordering at all.

Use backticks:

```
`produkte.preis`
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the single quotes from around `produkte.preis` in your `order by` clause or escape table name and column name with backtick:

Without escaping (as it's not necessary):

```
$ordered = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `produkte` ORDER BY produkte.preis");
```

Escaping with backticks:

```
$ordered = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `produkte` ORDER BY `produkte`.`preis`");
```

You need to escape table names and column names if they are one of the [MySQL Reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).